# Align Items using Css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align items like this.

Put 4 items in 1 row and the 3 items in next row but I want to align center.

Though I fixed with as 25% but it is not working properly.

Please have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e2rj21op/)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.quarter {
  width: 24.6%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #b5d46e;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>7</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>8</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ADD box-sizing:border-box to the class .quarter

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap each set of `.quarter` elements you want in a line, in their own flex-box. Make sure you give each `.quarter` the `flex:1;` property instead of `width:25%` property.

For example, this is your first row's HTML. Reference to the fiddle for all of the code, including where to put the `flex:1;` property.

```
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ogho96cf/

Answer (score 0):

> Put 4 items in 1 row and the 3 items in next row but I want to align center.

Not sure what we are suppose to do with the 8th item but...

Firstly, we use `box-sizing:border-box` to include padding/borders in the width calculations and the we can set the widths (or flex property) to:

```
.quarter {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}
```

..and we're done.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.quarter {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #b5d46e;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='quarter flex-item'>
    <h3>7</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I though he wanted 4/3/1 and @Wowsk had a better answer than me (for that approach). So dumb :P